# getting last record from the database with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure

```
recordId         mobileNumber         month            year          yearmonth
101               9900000000          4                2013           20134
102               9900000000          3                2013           20133
103               9900000000          1                2013           20131
104               9999999999          3                2013           20133
105               9999999999          2                2013           20132
106               9999999999          1                2013           20131
```

Suppose current month is 4 and year is 2013.

I need to get all the numbers from this table with their last entry . I had tried with this query

```
select * from tablename where yearmonth=(select max(yearmonth) from tablename)
```

but problem is that some numbers do not appears last month like number 999999999
has no value for the month 4 so it doesn't retrieve all the numbers.

How I can get the last record of all numbers.

Comment: umm, what will `yearmonth` look like for `month 10`?

Comment: actually, it stores like this 201301 so for month 10, it stores 201310 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mobileNumber ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, recordId DESC) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mobileNumber, max(yearmonth)
from tablename
group by mobileNumber
```